# Software RAID 1 with dissimilar size and performance drives

Tags: centos, filesystems, hard-disk, raid, storage

*Background*

I was experimenting with a home server setup in a small box I had that was supposed to be a media centre but never found much use. I installed CentOS 6.5 in a software RAID1 configuration accross two similarly specced laptop hard drives I had salvaged from an old device. Both are 320GB and both run at 7200rpm with the same sized cache. The install went ahead perfectly and I was happy with everything however now one of the drives is reporting S.M.A.R.T errors.

The only spare drive I have is a 5400rpm 1TB laptop drive. I dont need to rebuild the array and I will happily reinstall from scratch as the system hasnt been put to use yet but I dont wish to purchase a relatively expensive replacement 7200rpm 320GB drive.

*Question*

Is there anything inherently wrong/dangerous/unreliable about setting up software RAID 1 across the non-faulty 320GB drive and a 320GB partition of the 1TB drive then using the remainder of the 1TB drive as an additional non-redundant storage partition, bearing in mind the different sizes and spindle speeds? Will the partioner let me do this?

Note: I have browsed https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php and it constantly refers to devices "of roughly the same size."

Answer (score 2):

No. There is nothing wrong with that. It'll of course be slower than using two high-performance drives.

There is no reason to reinstall, just add the new drive to the existing array. Use the new mdadm replace functionality if you have it. Otherwise, I'd temporarily grow the array to 3 devices, let the sync complete, fail & remove the drive you're removing, and then shrink the array back to two devices.

Answer (score 2):

You can use disks of differents sizes and differents performances. It is just not optimal.

If you use a 320GB and a 1TB disk drive, then your RAID1 array will be 320GB. The rest will be unused.

Quite the same thing for performance. The slower disk will slow everything down. But nothing dangerous.

Comment: You can use a 320GB partition on the 1TB disk, and then the rest doesn't have to go to waste. One of the advantages of mdraid.

Answer (score 1):

If you manually add the new drive to your faulty RAID 1 array to repair it, then you can use the `-W` and `--write-behind` options to achieve some performance tuning:

**-W, --write-mostly**

> subsequent  devices listed in a --build, --create, or --add com- and
>   will be flagged as write-mostly  This is valid for RAID1 only  and 
>   means  that  the md driver will avoid reading from these devices if at
>   all possible.  This can be useful if mirroring over a slow link.

**--write-behind=**

> Specify  that  write-behind  mode  should  be enabled (valid for
>                 RAID1 only).  If an argument is specified, it will set the maximum  number of outstanding writes allowed.  The default value is
>                 256.  A write-intent bitmap is required in order to  use  write-
>                 behind mode, and write-behind is only attempted on drives marked
>                 as write-mostly.